# Write a Global Methods to check authentication in NuxtJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

I have difficulty to Write a Global Methods to check authentication in NuxtJS. The methods which I can write v-if in components to display if it return True.
I put this code in layout/default.vue but it doesn't works.

**/layout/defaut.vue**

```
<script>
import '~/assets/icons'
export default {
  head () {
    return !this.mobileLayout ? {} : {
      bodyAttrs: {
        class: 'mobile'
      }
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.LoggedIn()
  },
  methods: {
    LoggedIn: function () {
      return this.$store.state.authUser
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Components:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="LoggedIn">Authenticated</div >
</template>
```

Error:

```
Property or method "LoggedIn" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render
```

Hope you guy help me!

Answer (score 0):

Since `authUser` is a state property in vuex, not a method. `LoggedIn` in your component is simply returning a value from the state and does not need to be a method.

You should use a computed instead of a method. You also do not need to call `LoggedIn` from the created method, once it is a computed, it will be calculated automatically.

```
<script>
import '~/assets/icons'
export default {
  head () {
    return !this.mobileLayout ? {} : {
      bodyAttrs: {
        class: 'mobile'
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    LoggedIn: function () {
      return this.$store.state.authUser
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Or even better, use `mapState` from vuex which is documented here https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/state.html

```
<script>
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import '~/assets/icons'
export default {
  head () {
    return !this.mobileLayout ? {} : {
      bodyAttrs: {
        class: 'mobile'
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
        LoggedIn: 'authUser'
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Your template does not need to be changed.